# Box2D c++. Как перемещать по сцене статические тела, на которое не действуют законы физики?

Tags: c++, sfml, box2d, move, scale

У меня есть физический мир Box2D. В нем находятся статические объекты, которые находятся в воздухе и на них не действуют законы физики. Мне надо перетаскивать эти статические объекты по сцене зажатой кнопкой мыши.
Вопрос, как перемещать такие объекты или  через какую функцию это сделать? Тело у меня получает координаты, но c места не двигается. Пробовал использовать SetTransform(), тело двигается, но совершенно не понятно в каких координатах. Прошу помощи или разъяснения .

```
bdef_rect.type = b2_kinematicBody;
b2Vec2 center;
center.x = x / SCALE;
center.y = y / SCALE;
bshape_rect.SetAsBox(height_shape / SCALE, width_shape / SCALE, center, 0);
body_rect = world.CreateBody(&bdef_rect);
body_rect->CreateFixture(&bshape_rect, 1);
static_cast<Rectangle*>(it)->bdef_rect.position.Set(vec.x,vec.y);
```

Comment: SetTransform двигает в координатах мира box2d. Тут на самом деле не очень понятно, зачем пихать в box2d какие-то элементы, на которые физика никак не действует.

Comment: Это нужно для интерактивного моделирования сцены с помощью мышки. Чтобы не писать в коде.